# CasperJS - Uploading multiple images in form

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to automatically upload images to an form with CasperJS.

The problem, I've got is that I can't upload multiple images to an form. I even can't upload one. The form hasn't got any id and also the inputs have just a name-tag declared as "Filedata[]".

```html
<form action="bilderupload.php?---unimportant">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="">
    <tbody><tr>
       <td align="left">
       <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="ffullwidth c--inser__bild__orig">
       <tbody><tr>
         <td class="col1">
<input type="file" name="Filedata[]"> <input type="file" name="Filedata[]"> <input type="file" name="Filedata[]"> <input type="file" name="Filedata[]"> <input type="file" name="Filedata[]"> <input type="file" name="Filedata[]"> <input type="file" name="Filedata[]"> <input type="file" name="Filedata[]"> <input type="file" name="Filedata[]"> <input type="file" name="Filedata[]"> <input type="file" name="Filedata[]"> <input type="file" name="Filedata[]"> <input type="file" name="Filedata[]"> <input type="file" name="Filedata[]">          </td>
         <td class="col2" valign="top"><p class="helpinfo nomarg c--inser__bild__guidl">Anforderungen: max. 10 MB Dateigröße, min. 400 Pixel breit, Dateiformat jpg/jpeg.</p></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20"></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <input type="hidden" name="id_fahrzeug" value="7041031"><input type="hidden" name="original" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="f_eb" value="j"><input type="hidden" name="alternativ" value="1">
         <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Originalbilder hinzufügen</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="36"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="borderbox atteninfo"><strong>Bei der Verwendung</strong> von Symbol- oder Platzhalterbildern anstelle von Originalabbildungen wird das Inserat ohne weiteren Hinweis gelöscht!</div></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table></form>
```

I've tried to fill it with the fill command

```js
casper.then(function() {
   casper.wait(3000, function() {
     this.fill('form', {
                "FileData[]": ['Lamborghini-Aventador-9.jpg']
           }, false);
  });
});
```

...and also with the page.upload

```js
       var fileuploads = document.getElementsByName('input[type="file"]');
        this.page.uploadFile(fileuploads[0], filename);
```

but it is not working anyway. I have also looked up previous questions, but still don't work for me.

I do a screenshot after a delay of 10000ms. And the image is still not declared.

The goal is to upload pictures with this form and these inputs. Can you help me?
I don't know how to do it right now.

Comment: First of all. my recommendation would be to remove `[]` from the name of the `input fields`. The second is put more JS code. To what `this.fill` applies to though?

Comment: Ok I've updated it. It's in a Casper.then and also a wait, because it loads something before. After that I wait 3000ms more and take screenshot.

Comment: in documentation it's like

Comment: this.fill('form#contact-form', { 'categories': ['0', '1'] // Friends and Family });

Comment: First of all fix problem with CasperJS! Can't you see if you run the second snippet this error message `"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: casper is not defined"` ? Try to re-install CaspeJS or 
re-connect it. Then come back, will try to help you!

Comment: it's not with casper. I have already filled three other pages with it but the problem is: I can't fill the images right.

Comment: some more questions: which path should the image integrate? from root? or should i open it manually and look where the picture starts? can I get all of these input-fields and then call them each with inputfield[0], inputfield[1] and so on

Comment: For sure, `path` should be set directly from the folder you have your image(s). Double check that as well. About input fields would like to recommend you to use a `for` loop to populate them. This probably will solve the problem!